# Looking for a word for a rodent

Tags: animals

I am looking for a name of a rodent. It is two words of three letters each. The rodent is somehow related to the rat and guinea pig and "it is not white coated despite its name". The question comes from the game IAssociate, so the rodent is probably popular in the United States.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is "lab rat."  The hint about "white-coated" comes from the stereotypical white coat worn by researchers in laboratories.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Now that you told me the word it seems so obvious:-)

Answer (score 2):

I think they are looking for "lab rat"

Comment: Thank you, though I'll accept the Kith's answer because he was first.

Comment: Actually, Kit is a she (I made the same mistake once, because I hadn't gone into chat before, and also I had just read Dickens' *The Old Curiosity Shop*.)  The *ḫ* at the end of her name is a quirk, not really part of her pronounced name, AFAIK.

Comment: Ooops, sorry then. I do not have enough reputation to edit the comment though:)